# Netbeans on Windows

Tags: java, netbeans

After programming on Mac for a while I tried to program on windows for a change. I started to program but soon realised, what ever I put, the result will not show. I tried the most basic code on netbeans which is,

```
 public class NewClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello");
    }
}
```

On my Macbook it would give me "Hello" but on my Windows it would give me,

> "run: BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)" with no Hello what
>   soever...

Comment: You are running a build then. Congratulations. It built. Try running the actual project now. Note we cannot see how you are trying to do this, or what you are actually clicking on.

Comment: I tried all of it. Building, running the project, running the Java Application, Clean and build project, just building project. F6, F11... I tried but every time it gives me the same answer...

Comment: *update* I was fiddling around with my code and accidentally pressed Shift + F6. It worked... What is going on?